# Defining variables in SVG

Tags: xml, variables, path, svg, definition

I currently have a line filled in SVG like this:

```
<path d="M 0   45
         L 100 45
         L 100 55
         L 0   55
         Z" fill="gray" />
```

I would like to define the thickness as a variable instead of hardcoding so that the definition is something along the lines of:

```
<path d="M 0   50 - t
         L 100 50 - t
         L 100 50 + t
         L 0   50 + t
         Z" fill="gray" />
```

with `t = 5`.

Is this possible in a SVG document?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SVG itself has no such variables.

You can change the attributes of SVG elements clients-side (with JavaScript). A more robust and simple way is to generate the finished SVG (without variables) on the server, where you can use variables in the server-side programming language of your choice.

Comment: Note also that (although it can't be used in calculations as needed in this question) you can also define custom entities with an inline DTD and use them within your XML/SVG document.